# Why was camera.startPreview() deprecated?

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecated, android-camera2

I've recently been doing a lot of coding in android and I have not been able to understand the why behind so many of the changes that have happened with `android.hardware.Camera`.

For example, in `android.hardware.camera2` (I know its a package and not a class) why was the `startPreview()` option removed? I ask because `startPreview()` seems like a much easier, straightforward, and understandable way of previewing images than the very obfuscated and convoluted current way that I've encountered so far involving `CameraCaptureSession`, `CaptureRequest.Builder`, etc... Or are there simpler ways to accomplish this still? I have looked to try to understand these changes but it just all seems so drastically different from the previous implementation.

Comment: A possible simpler approach might be to take a look at camerax from androidx libs.

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not a good option for Stack Overflow. Only some Google engineer can tell you why a particular method was not included. Everyone else can only offer opinions. If you want a simpler API, there are many [camera libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created), though as Alex mentions, `androidx.camera` is worth considering.

Comment: This is not asking for people that do not know of the reason to answer but precisely for those that do know, however unlikely it is they might find this question. If you are worried about people offering opinions then that means you should try and stop those people... My question is entirely valid.